# How to add custom js for select in Wagtail choice block

Tags: javascript, django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield, wagtail-admin

My goal is to have *select* (dropdowns) handled by [custom-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-select) js library for blocks in **Wagtail Stream Field**. As it is quite easy to add for normal fields when event `DOMContentLoaded` is triggered. But is there any ***event*** or ***hook*** for adding a *block* to **StreamField**?

I tried even calling my function in html template for block. But it seems to be called too early because styles are not applied to selects in this html.

this is my `.js` *(typescript)*

```
const initColorChoosers = () => {
const colorChoosers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.color-chooser select')) as HTMLSelectElement[];
colorChoosers.forEach((chooser) => {
    if (!chooser.hasAttribute('custom')) {
        chooser.setAttribute("custom", "true")
        new CustomSelect(chooser, {
            customOptionClass: 'option--hero-glow-color'
        })
    }
})
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    window.myfuncs.initColorChoosers = () => initColorChoosers();
});
```

and my color chooser:

```
class Colors(blocks.ChoiceBlock):
choices = [
    ('color1', 'color1'),
    ('color2', 'color2'),
    ('color2', 'color2'),
]
required = False,

class Meta:
    form_classname = 'color-chooser'
    icon = 'copy'
```

and block template at the end contains:

```
<script>
    window.myfuncs.initColorChoosers()
</script>
```

And it works.. but for already added blocks not for the current one.
So if I add a block which contains ColorChooser, it won't apply logic from `custom-select` but when I add another one, for the first one changes will be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a BlockAdapter (relevant to the block type - if it's a StructBlock, then StructBlockAdapter) and JavaScript Blockdefinition (same again, relevant to block type, StructBlock -> StructBlockDefinition.

Wagtail docs: https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/streamfield_blocks.html#additional-javascript-on-structblock-forms

How to article:
https://enzedonline.com/en/tech-blog/how-to-create-wagtail-streamfield-structblocks-with-a-customised-editor-interface/

Wagtail will load an instance of the BlockDefintion each time you add that block to the streamfield.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that is exactly what I am looking for. But still have some issue with that.

When I register adapter, `window.telepath` seems to be not yet introduced and some errors appears when calling some of it methods such us `unpack`. When 
 I delete my adapter registration and page loads fully `window.telepath` is fully available.

Comment: Ah - just answered your question in slack before I saw this. Probably easier to help out there 